# Reading from a file problems

Tags: java, nosuchelementexception

I am getting a NoSuchElementException when I am trying to read info from a file to create an object.  Can anyone help me see what is going wrong?

```
else if(response == 3){
    System.out.println("Enter the name of the file to load items from: ");
    loadFile = input.nextLine();
    try {
        infile = new Scanner(new FileReader(loadFile+".txt"));
    }
    catch(IOException err) {
        infile = null;
        System.out.println("Cannot open file\n");
    }
    while(infile.hasNext()){
        itemType = infile.next();
        name = infile.next();
        itemDescription = infile.next();
        itemCalories = infile.nextInt();
        itemPrice = infile.nextDouble();
        itemSpecific = infile.nextLine();
        createNewObject(counter, itemType, name, itemDescription, itemCalories, itemPrice, itemSpecific);
    }
}
```

My file 'items' is arranged as so:

```
Doughnut                                  
Jellydoughnut                        
Roundwithfrosting                             
100                                  
1.22                                  
creamfilling
```

Comment: Look at the exceptions's stack trace. It will tell you what line the problem is on.

Answer (score 2):

You're checking `hasNext()` just once, and then getting a bunch of tokens without checking. That's dangerous. Each `nextXXX()` should be preceded by a `hasNextXXX()`.

Comment: can you give me an example i don't understand?                                so hasNextInt instead of nextInt?